# Private JVM with smaller file-size

Tags: deployment, bundle, java

I am looking to bundle JRE with my app, since that is Apple's requirement for submission to the appstore. Using the standard JRE libraries increases the file-size from 1 mb to 153 mb.

Can anybody recommend an alternative JRE that has much smaller file-size?

Comment: which plattform is your target OS? iOS, MacOS?

Comment: Can you suggest the user have Java installed already or download it on demand from Oracle?

Comment: What about removing all not needed classes from the  standard JRE libraries (*rt.jar*)?

Comment: Simulant: Mac  | Peter Lawrey, yes, but I need to package in .app. | MrSmith42 Which classes do I need to remove and how small would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

Downloaded OpenJDK and deleted the files specified on [this page](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/BundlingJRE). Reduced the size of JVM to 39 mb for me.